# Let high priority python thread to enter the critical section while low priority thread is execution in the critical section

Tags: python, python-3.x, multithreading

I have set of threads which can execute a synchronized method in python. Currently when a thread comes to critical section it enters to the critical section if no thread is executing the critical section. Otherwise  wait and enter the critical section after lock is released. (it works as synchronization supposed to work). But I have a high priority thread which should enter the critical section whether a low priority thread is in the critical section or not. Is this possible? If so how can I implement this?

Comment: You can write your own decorator that applies the lock to the threads that are not prioritized only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ones a thread has acquired the mutex, then no other thread can enter that critical section until it releases it. In other words you can not do what you are asking for.

Threads are completely controlled by the [Scheduling process](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scheduling_(computing)) and it is uknown which thread will be the first to acquire the mutex.

The reason why you can not do this is simple straight forward because the whole point of the mutexes are to prevent other threads to do the same you wanna do.

For example, if a thread is already in the critical section and another thread get's access to it (let's say by pausing the thread that already is in that section) then there is a high chance for a [race condition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Race_condition) to happen.

Comment: Got the idea. It's impossible indeed. Thanks for clarification.

Comment: Thank you. If you think of it, you don't really need to give priority to a thread because threads are running fast enough to not notice any difference. The operating system, with a smart and good Scheduler make certain of that. Don't forget to vote my answer please.

Comment: Yeah.. I found some indirect solution for my issue.

Answer (score 2):

As another answer described very well, this is not possible, there is no way to do it.

What you can and often should do is prevent another lower priority thread from entering this critical section first, before high priority thread.

I.e. if a critical section is being held by some thread, this thread needs to exit it first. But by that time there might be multiple threads waiting for this critical section, some low and some high priority. You may want to ensure higher priority thread gets the critical section first in such situation.

Comment: This is a really good idea! If you combine it with a data structure that keep priority levels, it might work pretty well! I did not thought of that. Nice answer!